# Do I need `<html>` for sending HTML email using Swift

Tags: html, swiftmailer

I want to send an HTML with swift. Do I need to create an `html` email including `<html>`and `<head>`, `<body>` tag, or will switfmailer do this automatically?

For example, if I want to sent the html email with the content `My <em>amazing</em> body` is it then sufficent to use

```
// Or set it after like this
$message->setBody('My <em>amazing</em> body', 'text/html');
```

or do I need to write

```
// Set the body
$message->setBody(
'<html>' .
' <head></head>' .
' <body>' .
' My <em>amazing</em> body' . 
' </body>' .
'</html>',
  'text/html' // Mark the content-type as HTML
);
```

Whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send emails with html content, you have to

1. set the content type to `text/html`:

   `$message->setBody($yourHtml, 'text/html');`
2. use html content which the clients tolerate and display properly.

This might have not much to do with a properly formed html message. Many email clients tend to not follow web standards. Therefore I suggest using an online validator to check your html content against different, commonly used email clients. A few examples:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validate_email
- http://emaillint.com/

By the way, with swiftmailer you can even add both content types within one email, like this:

```
[...]
$message->setBody('My <em>html</em> body', 'text/html');
$message->addPart('My plain text', 'text/plain');
[...]
```